# can use while loop within for loop?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int input, x, c=0;
for (input=1; input<=100; input++)
{
    while(input != 0)
    {
        x = input%10;
        c = c*10 + x;
        input = input/10;
    }
    printf("Reverse Number is : %d", c);
 }
```

This is the reverse number code, but this code printing minus value.
Why this code printing minus values?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question in the title does not match the question in the body. Which question do you want to ask?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then edit your question to include your output and expected output.

Comment: How exactly does this code make any sense? `c` will be `1` then `11` then `111` and so on until it overflows, because you keep setting `input` to zero. What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: There are a few issues: 1) You modify your loop variable inside the loop. That will mess up the outer loop. 2) Also you never reset `c`. You should do that for each new number. Maybe you get negative output because the variable overflows but without your output we cannot tell.

Comment: Where is your main function()? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can use while loops inside for loops. Though, you should be careful while doing so. I noticed a few issues with your code.

First of all, your template isn't correct, so it's weird it even compiles, so let me quickly fix that for you

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int input, x, c = 0;
    for (input = 1; input <= 100; input++)
    {
        while(input != 0)
        {
            x = input % 10;
            c = c * 10 + x;
            input = input / 10;
        }
        printf("Reverse Number is : %d\n", c);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now let's look at what happens to the `input` variable in the for loop:

1. `input = 1`
2. `while(input != 0)` makes so when the while loop ends, `input == 0`
3. The for loop starts again, `++input == 1`.

So, as result, the for loop became an infinite loop, where the `input` variable is always equal to 1. To fix that, we need to introduce a temporary variable in the loop, so `input` holds its value till the next iteration. Let's do that.

```c
    for (input = 1; input <= 100; input++)
    {
        int temp = input;
        while(temp != 0)
        {
            x = temp % 10;
            c = c * 10 + x;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        printf("Reverse Number is : %d\n", c);
    }
```

The next issue is that there's no place where you reset the value of `c`. Therefore it only gets larger and eventually [overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). To fix that we need to reset the value of `c` before the while loop starts.

```c
    for (input = 1; input <= 100; input++)
    {
        int temp = input;
        c = 0;
        while(temp != 0)
        {
            x = temp % 10;
            c = c * 10 + x;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        printf("Reverse Number is : %d\n", c);
    }
```

And, that's it!

The result will look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int input, x, c = 0;
    for (input = 1; input <= 100; input++)
    {
        int temp = input;
        c = 0;
        while(temp != 0)
        {
            x = temp % 10;
            c = c * 10 + x;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        printf("Reverse Number is : %d\n", c);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```